# How do I add the elements of several lists in python

Tags: python, for-loop, design-patterns, sum

I am trying to calculate the total number of convergent hailstone sequences. In the code below I am determining whether a sequence is convergent or divergent for different values of a, b, and x and outputting a list (seems to be a list of lists with one element in each sublist). My issue here is I can't seem to find the TOTAL number of convergent sequences. I would like to add all the 1's in my list and output the final value to obtain this answer. Can anybody please help?

P.S. In the output below, 1 = convergent 0 = divergent.

Here's my code:

```
def hailstone(a, b, x):
    list = []
    c = 0
    count = []
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if x%2 == 0:
            x = x/2
        else:
            x = a * x + b
        if x not in list:
            list.append(x)
        else:
            break
    if len(list) < 99:
        c = 1 + c
        count.append(c)
    else: pass
    return(count)

def run():
    for a in range(1, 4):
        for b in range(1, 4):
            for x in range(1, 4):
                print(hailstone(a,b,x))      

run()
```

Here's the output

```
[1]
[1]
[1]
[]
[]
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[]
[]
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[]
[]
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
[]
[]
[]
[1]
[1]
[1]
```

Also, here's the data type for my list count:

```
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
<class 'list'>
```

Comment: Do you except the output to be 5 or 15? Are you counting a hailstone sequence (defined by `a` and `b`) as convergent only if it converges for all values of `x` tested?

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to count number of one or zero, the best will be to return value of c on behalf of the count list (which will contain or 1 or will be empty...)

```
def hailstone(a, b, x):
    list = []
    c = 0
    #count = []
    for i in range(1, 100):
        if x%2 == 0:
            x = x/2
        else:
            x = a * x + b
        if x not in list:
            list.append(x)
        else:
            break
    if len(list) < 99:
        c = 1
    else: pass
    return(c)

def run():
    hailstone_list=[] 
    for a in range(1, 4):
        for b in range(1, 4):
            for x in range(1, 4):
                hailstone_list. append(hailstone(a,b,x))   

     print(hailstone_list.count(1))

run()
```

Answer (score 0):

Similar to @Renaud, I simplified your code some to make it more idiomatic (added some comments to indicate changes). This assumes you mean to return `5` (covergent sequences are `(1,1),(1,3),(2,2),(3,1),(3,3)`).

```
# Convert into a T/F (boolean) method for any a, b, x triplet
def is_convergent(a, b, x):
    s = set()  # Use a set for O(1) lookups, not O(n)
    for i in range(1, 100):
        x = (a * x + b) if (x % 2) else (x / 2)
        if x in s:
          return True  # this triplet converged, return True
        s.add(x)
    return False

def run():
    c = 0
    for a in range(1, 4):
        for b in range(1, 4):
            c += all([is_convergent(a,b,x) for x in range(1, 4)])
    return c

print(run())
```

If you meant to return 15, simply replace `all` with `sum`.